# How do I get the Chinese tilde "哇～～～" to look right?

Tags: tilde, chinese

> 哇～～～，你太棒了！

This usage of the Chinese tilde ～ needs to look the above: the tilde has the same width as a Chinese character, and is in the center vertically.  However, it comes out looking like:

> [image]

(I'm on Overleaf using XeLaTeX.)

**Question**: How do I get the Chinese tilde "哇～～～" to look right?

---

Here's a MWE for my local computer (also using XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpinyin}

\begin{document}

hello  哇～～～，你太棒了！
 
\end{document}
```

> [image]

(I'm not sure why, but it only displays the Chinese if I use the xpinyin package.)

Comment: Can you share a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)? I’m not sure what packages you’re using or what commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My browser used `Microsoft YaHei` to show your question, so I used the same with xetex:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Microsoft YaHei}

\begin{document}

哇～～～

\end{document}
```

On Overleaf the available Chinese fonts are listed  here

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Chinese

so you just need to pick one that you like and has a reasonable full width tilde.

eg this project with Noto Sans CJK

https://www.overleaf.com/read/pyxqhxxtzhdj

[image]

Comment: Thanks, changing the font works, although I'd be better off changing it locally.  Using `哇{\CJKfontspec{Noto Serif CJK SC:style=Regular}～～～}，你太棒了！` [looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7qVb.png).